# The grasses blew in our house

Tags: grammar

The park's grasses in front of our house were cut yesterday.

Today the grass blew in our car porch.

> "The grasses blew in our house."
>
> "The grasses blew in our home."

Car porch is part of the house.

If I using house, it sounds like the grass is blew "in" the house.

Based on the context above, we should use house or home?

[image]

Comment: Why did you switch between *grass* and *grasses*?

Comment: The pieces of grass which have been cut off are the grass *clippings* or *trimmings* (I hear *clippings* much more often in the U.S., also as *yard clippings* or *lawn clippings*).

Comment: What is a "car porch"?  Do you mean a "carport"?

Comment: A place in front of the house that car park on.

Comment: That a car parks _on_? Or _in_?

Comment: A car parks on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Grass" is one of those weird English nouns where the countable "grasses" means something different from the uncountable "grass".  "Grasses" will refer to a number of varieties or species of *grass*, while *grass* refers to some quantity of the stuff.

So a native English speaker would say:

> The **grass** blew into the house.

Otherwise it's much the same whether you say it blew into *the house* or into *our home* -- aside from the fact that a *house* is not the same thing as a *home*. If you say that something came into your *home* then it sounds more like an *invasion* than an *accident*.  Grass is pretty innocuous, but you might feel more strongly about something like people or insects:

> I don't know how these ants keep getting into **the house**!

vs.

> I don't know how these ants keep getting into **our home**!

Comment: I think that _house_ sounds better than _home_ in this context, though both are certainly acceptable.

Comment: @J.R.  I added more detail to address that.